# While joining two arrays, postfix non-unique values with (number) incrementally of joining array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays:

- Array 1 : `[{name: "Darin", id: "123"}, {name: "Mads", id: "345"}, {name: "Kenneth", id: "543"}, {name: "June", id: "567"}, {name: "June (1)", id: "789"}]`
- Array 2 : `[{name: "Darin", id: "910"}, {name: "June", id: "911"}, {name: "Simon", id: "912"}, {name: "Justin", id: "913"}]`

The output that I want is as follows:

```
[{name: "Darin", id: "123"}, {name: "Mads", id: "345"}, {name: "Kenneth", id: "543"}, {name: "June", id: "567"}, {name: "June (1)", id: "789"}, {name: "Darin (1)", id: "910"}, {name: "June (2)", id: "911"}, {name: "Simon", id: "912"}, {name: "Justin", id: "913"}]
```

As you can see, I have the following rules:

- Array 2 should be the only array in which I postfix (...num)
- Eventual duplicates should be postfixed with (number) where number increments until the value becomes unique in the joined array

I'm unsure where to start in order to achieve the above. I can see this solved with a bunch of loops and a recusive function - But really, that's inefficient.

I can see that Javascript ES6 offers some "newer" methods that could pose handy in this scenario - In particular [map and set](https://javascript.info/map-set).

Consequently, my question seeks to understand how I can achieve the above, while paying attention to time complexity.

Comment: Is the data set you need to do this on large enough to even warrant thinking about time complexity? I would just throw all those values together into one array, and remove any existing `(xy)` postfixes while doing so. And then loop over that, and add them where necessary - probably using an object to keep count of how many time each value already occurred.

Comment: Yep, that could be one solution - But then you risk violating the rule that Array 2 should be the only one subject to edits. 

The logic is supposed to be stored in a stored procedure in cosmosDB @CBroe so I would want it to be very efficient.

Comment: _"But then you risk violating the rule that Array 2 should be the only one subject to edits."_ - why? Unless you could have `[..., "June", "June"]` in your first array already, and wanted to _keep_ those as they are, I don't see how that could be problematic. (And then the counting process would also get more complex, then you'd really have to keep track of what array a value originated in.)

Comment: Its a good question - But this is tied to a UI -  i.e. the user will move Array 2 to Array 1. The user will get confused if Array 2 is the one subject to being moved and the receiving Array 1 then gets altered too. :-)

Comment: @CBroe I updated my question - It is actually an array of objects with name and ID. I didn't think it mattered when I asked the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Array.map, and a counter object to keep track of the number of times each name already occurred:

```js
var input1 = [{name: "Darin", id: "123"}, {name: "Mads", id: "345"}, {name: "Kenneth", id: "543"}, {name: "June", id: "567"}, {name: "June (1)", id: "789"}];

var input2 = [{name: "Darin", id: "910"}, {name: "June", id: "911"}, {name: "Simon", id: "912"}, {name: "Justin", id: "913"}];

var counter = {};
var combined = input1.concat(input2).map(function(e) {
  var strippedName = e.name.replace(/ \([0-9]+\)/, '');
  counter[strippedName] = counter[strippedName] == undefined ? 0 : counter[strippedName] + 1;
  e.name = strippedName + (counter[strippedName] ? ' ('+counter[strippedName]+')' : '');
  return e;
});
console.log(combined);
```

Comment: As far as I can see, if `{name: "Darin", id: "123"}` was changed to Darin (1) we are editing array 1 - because effectively this strips away the (1)?

Comment: No, first item still contains `{name: "Darin", id: "123"}`? Only the "latter" Darin, with id 910, has gotten a counter added. I am stripping the existing counter off first for purposes of counting, but then in the replacing part it easier to work with that already stripped name as well, otherwise the first `June (1)` that already existed in the input data, became `June (1) (1)`

Comment: Shouldn't it then be: 

`e.name = (counter[strippedName] ? strippedName + ' ('+counter[strippedName]+')' : e.name);` so that in case nothing is contained in the counter, we return the original value?

Comment: Yeah, that would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the names by separating the strings.

```js
const
    array1 = ["Darin", "Mads", "Kenneth", "June", "June (1)"],
    array2 = ["Darin", "June", "Simon", "Justin"],
    counts = {},
    result = [array1, array2].reduce((r, a) => {
        a.forEach(v => {
            const [, name, , count = 0] = v.match(/^(\w*)(\s\((\d+)\))?$/);
            if (name in counts && count === 0) ++counts[name];
            else counts[name] = count;
            r.push(counts[name] ? `${name} (${counts[name]})` : name);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```